# i'm trying to creat web page with flask but getting this error from the beginning

Tags: python, flask, peewee

i'm trying to install pip

`sudo apt -get install python3 -pip`

but i get this error

`Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)`

then flask

```
sudo pip install flask
```

and i got this error 
`sudo: pip: command not found`

then peewee

`sudo pip install peewee`

`sudo: pip: command not found`

anyone can help?

Comment: Are you actually on a Linux (if yes, which OS/distro?)? That path in the error looks like a macOS path

Comment: no i'm on mac,
but i'm looking for a tutorial on youtube for creating webpage by python and flask from scratch

Comment: There is no `apt -get` on macOS. Install Python either from the official website or using something like Homebrew.

Comment: i'm trying to follow this tutorial https://youtu.be/qla-KaMF-2Q
but i'm getting the same error
sudo pip install flask
command not found

Comment: Make sure you have python installation(Python 3) exists in your system. To do that you can try this: `command -v python3` or `which python3`, if you see the path for python3 executable you are fine (in this case run `python3 -V` command to see exact version of Python3); if not, you need to installed it first. After that, you need to re run the previous step for `pip` and/or `pip3`: `which pip` etc. If `pip` is not installed, install it.